# How to add a grid in an dialog

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin-flow

I need to put a grid in dialog but the grid is very small.

```
Grid<FermetureGagnanteTexte> fermetureGagnanteTexteGrid = new Grid<>(FermetureGagnanteTexte.class,false);
verticalLayout.add(fermetureGagnanteTexteGrid);
dialog.add(verticalLayout);`
dialog.open();
```

The grid is very small in the dialog.

Comment: @d2k2 sure there is a [Dialog Component](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-dialog/java-examples) in **vaadin flow**.

Comment: @LeoBrousset please describe your problem in more detail. How does your current solution look, how do you want it to look, and what have you tried to get there? for example have you tried setting the width or height of the grid (or/and the verticalLayout between dialog and grid) to the size of your liking?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for `Vaadin 8` by using the `Window` Component.

By the description of your problem i assume that you did not set any size attributes with `setWidth`, `setHeight` or `setSizefull`. Even my code example is specific for Vaadin 8 it should also apply to the Dialog-component for Vaadin-Flow.

[image]

```
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI;
import com.vaadin.ui.Grid;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;

@SpringUI
public class TestUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(final VaadinRequest request) {

        showGridInWindow();

    }

    private void showGridInWindow() {

        final Window window = new Window("Window Caption");

        final Grid<Object> grid = new Grid<>();
        grid.addColumn(Object::toString).setCaption("Column 1");
        grid.setSizeFull();

        final List<Object> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            items.add(new String("String #" + i));
        }

        grid.setItems(items);

        window.setContent(grid);
        window.setWidth("600px");
        window.setHeight("400px");
        window.setModal(true);
        window.setClosable(true);

        getUI().addWindow(window);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vaadin Flow, put the grid into a Div() instead of a VerticalLayout.  Add the Div to the Dialog and set the Dialog's size. The Grid should fill the space and scroll.

```
Grid<FermetureGagnanteTexte> grid = new Grid<>(FermetureGagnanteTexte.class);
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
Div div = new Div();
div.add(grid);
dialog.add(div);
dialog.setWidth("600px");

dialog.open();
```

S.